# configuring stack correctly on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, haskell-stack

I am very new to haskell I have installed stack but almost nothing is working.

For example:

```
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$ stack install cassava
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-9.18 from implicit global project's config file: /home/local/CORVIL/lpuggini/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
Invalid package ID: "array-0.5.1.1 base-4.9.1.0 binary-0.8.3.0 bytestring-0.10.8.1"
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$
```

and

```
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$ stack upgrade
Fetched package index.                                                                                    
Populated index cache.    
Cabal file warning in /tmp/stack-upgrade8199/stack-1.6.1/stack.cabal: Ignoring unknown section type: custom-setup
Cabal file warning in /tmp/stack-upgrade8199/stack-1.6.1/stack.cabal: Ignoring unknown section type: custom-setup
Invalid package ID: "array-0.5.1.1 base-4.9.1.0 binary-0.8.3.0 bytestring-0.10.8.1"
```

Here are some info:

```
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$ which stack
/usr/bin/stack
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$ stack --version
Version 0.1.10.0 x86_64
```

I assume that I am running an old version of stack. 
I think I should run it from `~/.stack` but I can not find the right launcher:

```
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$ ls .stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.0.2/bin/
ghc  ghc-8.0.2  ghci  ghci-8.0.2  ghc-pkg  ghc-pkg-8.0.2  haddock  haddock-ghc-8.0.2  hp2ps  hpc  hsc2hs  runghc  runghc-8.0.2  runhaskell
lpuggini@lpuggini-T3420:~$
```

What is that I am doing wrong? How can I solve?

Comment: That's a very very old version. Please upgrade. Get started from here: https://haskell-lang.org/get-started

Comment: but I think the version that is in .stack is the most recent one. The problem is that I do not know how to access to it.  In python I would have done something like `source .stack/bin`

Comment: @Donbeo If you think you do have a recent version of stack installed (as well as an old one), first delete the old one, then locate the new one and make sure its location is on your path.

Comment: `~/.stack` isn't a typical location for the stack executable. `stack upgrade` (which probably wasn't available in v0.1.10) will usually place it in `~/.local/bin`. You should follow Sibi's advice and do a fresh install.